# Is there any way of saving queries quota in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Free version of Firebase has limits for queries. 
Is there any way of checking if the data changed since last download or not. 
Of course, I can make a field 'changedAt' in my JSON schema and check in by myself, but every time I check it I make a distinct query to Firebase and it eats my quota. Is there ay meta info or some way of checking 'data version' so that those queries not reduced my quota?

Comment: What limits are you referring to, and how are they affecting your code?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about for your queries?  What are you trying to do that's not going to work?

Comment: Everything is working. I am just trying to save money - https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb